# rails routes logout how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am create twitter_zombie rails fro fun.
I just have one problem,when I click the logout, will jump to index.But I want to when I click the logout it will be jump the page that I Specified. which is 'tweets" page
sorry about my poor english.
here is routes.rb file

```
TwitterZombie::Application.routes.draw do



  devise_for :users

 # get "user/login"

 # get "user/logout"

 # get "tweets/index"

 # get "tweets/new"

 # get "tweets/create"

  #get "tweets/update"

  #get "tweets/destroy"

  #get "tweets/show"

 # get "tweets/edit"

  resources :tweets
  resources :zombies


  root :to =>'twees#index'

  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  #match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define route like this

```
match '/logout', :to => 'sessions#logout'
```

where *session* is controller, and *logout* is action.